# How to dismiss nginx warning message nginx: [alert] could not open error log file: open() "/var/log/nginx/error.log" failed (13: Permission denied)

Tags: nginx

I'm running nginx using common user not root. I have nginx installed system-wide, but have nginx.conf in HOME.

**$HOME/nginx/nginx.conf**

```
worker_processes  1;
error_log  /home/worker/nginx/log/nginx/error.log warn;
pid        /home/worker/nginx/run/nginx.pid;
events {
  worker_connections  1024;
}
http {
  include      /etc/nginx/mime.types;
  default_type application/octet-stream;
  access_log   /home/worker/nginx/log/nginx/access.log;
  server {
    listen 8080;
    root /home/worker/nginx/data;
  }
}
```

start nginx

```
$ nginx -c /home/worker/nginx/nginx.conf
nginx: [alert] could not open error log file: open() "/var/log/nginx/error.log" failed (13: Permission denied)
```

As you can see in the nginx.conf, I have defined `error_log`, but I still got the warning message:

```
nginx: [alert] could not open error log file: open() "/var/log/nginx/error.log" failed (13: Permission denied)
```

nginx itself works, just want to remove this warning message, how can I do that?

Comment: Hmm. I misread this at first. I suspect somebody else did too. Are you sure that is your entire nginx configuration?

Comment: @MichaelHampton Sorry for my bad English. Thank you for your time, yes. this is the minimal conf file that can produce the issue.

Comment: Have you tried: `nginx -q -c /home/worker/nginx/nginx.conf`?

Comment: @RichardSmith Just tried, no change.

Comment: Add `sudo` before `nginx...` command $ sudo nginx ...

Answer (score 5):

Recently (2020-11-19), an `-e` option was added to nginx, allowing you to override the error log path that has been compiled in. You can use that option to point nginx to a user-writeable file (or maybe `stderr`).

See https://trac.nginx.org/nginx/changeset/f18db38a9826a9239feea43c95515bac4e343c59/nginx

Comment: basically a link-only answer. I'm curious how to send errors to stderr

Comment: @DevinRhode this flag is [documented now](https://nginx.org/en/docs/switches.html). 
You have to use `nginx -e stderr`

Answer (score 5):

I'm late to the party, but I've had this issue for another reason. I simply added the access rights to the folder and files for nginx (`www-data` user in my case):

```
sudo chown -R www-data:www-data /var/log/nginx
```

I've actually removed the whole folder and log file and recreated them:

```
sudo rm -rf /var/log/nginx
sudo mkdir /var/log/nginx
sudo touch /var/log/nginx/error.log
sudo chown -R www-data:www-data /var/log/nginx
```

Maybe there is a more elegant solution.

Answer (score 3):

This error is shown because the user executing `nginx` does not have permission to view the log file created by the ngnix process, which is most likely owned by `www-data` and not the user. Running the command with sudo, if possible, or giving the user permissions on the error log will eliminate the error message being shown.

Comment: Yes this helped me. I was using : $ nginx -t
nginx: [alert] could not open error log file: open() "/var/log/nginx/error.log" failed (13: Permission denied)
2022/06/18 16:23:43 [warn] 5039#5039: the "user" directive makes sense only if the master process runs with super-user privileges, ignored in /etc/nginx/nginx.conf:1
nginx: the configuration file /etc/nginx/nginx.conf syntax is ok
2022/06/18 16:23:43 [emerg] 5039#5039: open() "/run/nginx.pid" failed (13: Permission denied)
nginx: configuration file /etc/nginx/nginx.conf test failed but then I used:$ sudo nginx -t
..conf syntax is ok

Comment: Running a web service with superuser power exposes your app to external threads. Please do not do that, is a very bad habit.
Regards.

Comment: `sudo nginx -t` and errors are elimated. nginx syntax ok and test successful.

Answer (score 1):

There doesn't seem to be a way to eliminate this "alert".

See same question in StackOverflow:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34258894/nginx-still-try-to-open-default-error-log-file-even-though-i-set-nginx-config-fi